# Flextable - Change amount of decimals based on rows

Tags: r, format, digits, xtable, flextable

So I am trying to create an flextable in Rstudio. The data in this flextable contains a lot of converted and calculated data which makes it slightly difficult to reproduce, so I hope the original code will be enough. My apologies for that!

Before creating a flextable I check wether the data, which is to be converted, is correct:

```
datt2 <- xtable(dat4, digits = 3)
```

Which shows me:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & Ruimte1 & Ruimte2 & Ruimte3 & Ruimte4 & Ruimte5 & Ruimte6 & Ruimte7 & gem.beoordeling \\ 
  \hline
Laagopgeleid & 2.860 & 2.290 & 2.500 & 2.320 & 2.900 & 3.060 & 2.450 & 2.620 \\ 
  Hoogopgeleid & 2.880 & 2.280 & 2.560 & 2.460 & 3.240 & 3.150 & 2.670 & 2.750 \\ 
  T-test & 0.937 & 0.989 & 0.821 & 0.596 & 0.138 & 0.648 & 0.428 & 0.228 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This seems fine to me and ready to create a flextable. The only adjustment that needs to be made is "Laagopgeleid" and "Hoogopgeleid" need to be adjusted to 2 decimal. "T-test" needs to be left on 3 decimals. Looking through various instructions about colformat_double I came to the following code:

```
date2 <- datt2 %>% xtable_to_flextable() %>% 
  fontsize(part = "header", size = 20) %>%
  fontsize(part = "body", size = 18) %>%
  align_text_col(align = "left") %>% 
  align_nottext_col(align = "center") %>% 
  width(width = 1.8) %>%
  width(j = 1, width = 3.3) %>%
  height_all(height = .5) %>%
  border_inner(border = std_border) %>% 
  font(fontname = "Open Sans") %>%
  colformat_double(j = c("Ruimte1", "Ruimte2", "Ruimte3",
                      "Ruimte4", "Ruimte5", "Ruimte6",
                      "Ruimte7", "gem.beoordeling"), digits = 3) %>%
  colformat_double(i = Laagopgeleid, Hoogopgeleid, digits = 2) %>% 
  color(part = "header", color = d)
```

The first colformat_double (digits = 3) works just fine, I can even change it to something else and it does whatever I want. But the second colformat_double(i = Laagopgeleid, Hoogopgeleid) does something extremely weird, It changes "Hoogopgeleid" as shown[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMFLJ.jpg). It does not matter which row I mention at (i = ) or in which order it only changes "Hoogopgeleid". Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE:
Ill just provide the whole code so you wont miss out on any information. I dont want make hasty judgement but I did found that the rownames are set to character while trying to create a flextable with rownames... as I keep trying to use colformat_double.. maybe this has something to do with it as well?

```
per = ((df$opleiding.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]+df$opleiding.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])/ 
         (df$opleiding.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]+
            df$opleiding.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]+
            df$opleiding.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]+
            df$opleiding.4.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]))

per[is.na(per)] <- 0 #filters all NA or - and sets it to 0

words_to_num <- function(word){
  return(switch(word, "Geen mening"={NA}, "Erg ontevreden"={1}, "Niet erg tevreden"={2}, "Redelijk tevreden"={3}, "Zeer tevreden"={4}))
} #switches words to numbers

digits_to_words <- function(digit){
  return(switch(digit, "1"={"Erg ontevreden"}, "2"={"Niet erg tevreden"}, "3"={"Redelijk tevreden"}, "4"={"Zeer tevreden"}))
} #changes the numbers back to words in order to get the average opinion

Ruimte1 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte2 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte3 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte4 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.4.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte5 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.5.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte6 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.6.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
Ruimte7 <- as.integer(sapply(df$openbareruimte.7.[df$startvraag=="Ja"], words_to_num))
#Changes the dataset from words to numbers
#To give you an idea, this is what ruimte1 looks like after this
#> Ruimte1
# [1] 4 4 3 2 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 1 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 3 4
#[42] 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 1 3

R0 = data.frame(Ruimte1, Ruimte2, Ruimte3, Ruimte4, Ruimte5, Ruimte6, Ruimte7)
df$gemiddeld.Openbareruimte[df$startvraag=="Ja"] <- rowMeans(R0, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 4)
#Creates the rowmean of ruimte1, 2 etc... filters out NA while doing this.

dat1 <- data.frame(
  df$opleiding.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
  df$opleiding.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
  df$opleiding.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
  df$opleiding.4.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
  Percentage = per,
  Ruimte1,
  Ruimte2,
  Ruimte3,
  Ruimte4,
  Ruimte5,
  Ruimte6,
  Ruimte7,
  df$gemiddeld.Openbareruimte[df$startvraag=="Ja"])
#Putting the above in a df to get the information I need

names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "df.opleiding.1..df.startvraag.....Ja.."] <- "Opl1"
names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "df.opleiding.2..df.startvraag.....Ja.."] <- "Opl2"
names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "df.opleiding.3..df.startvraag.....Ja.."] <- "Opl3"
names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "df.opleiding.4..df.startvraag.....Ja.."] <- "Opl4"
names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "Percentage"] <- "(Opl1+Opl2)/ (Opl1+Opl2+Opl3+Opl4)"
names(dat1)[names(dat1) == "df.gemiddeld.Openbareruimte.df.startvraag.....Ja.."] <- "Gemiddeld /n Openbare Ruimte"
#changes the column names of dat1

Laag <- dat1 %>% 
  filter(per <= 0.5)
Laag1<- sum(Laag$`Gemiddeld /n Openbare Ruimte`) / nrow(Laag)
#getting the average based on education level <= 50%

LR1 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte1)
LR1 <- colMeans(LR1, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR2 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte2)
LR2 <- colMeans(LR2, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR3 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte3)
LR3 <- colMeans(LR3, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR4 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte4)
LR4 <- colMeans(LR4, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR5 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte5)
LR5 <- colMeans(LR5, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR6 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte6)
LR6 <- colMeans(LR6, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
LR7 = data.frame(Laag$Ruimte7)
LR7 <- colMeans(LR7, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
# Getting the average on each ruimte# and filter out NA

Hoog <- dat1 %>% 
  filter(per > 0.5)
Hoog1 <- sum(Hoog$`Gemiddeld /n Openbare Ruimte`) / nrow(Hoog)

HR1 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte1)
HR1 <- colMeans(HR1, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR2 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte2)
HR2 <- colMeans(HR2, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR3 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte3)
HR3 <- colMeans(HR3, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR4 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte4)
HR4 <- colMeans(HR4, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR5 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte5)
HR5 <- colMeans(HR5, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR6 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte6)
HR6 <- colMeans(HR6, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)
HR7 = data.frame(Hoog$Ruimte7)
HR7 <- colMeans(HR7, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(digits = 2)

RT1 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte1, Laag$Ruimte1)
RT1 <- data.frame(RT1$p.value)
RT2 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte2, Laag$Ruimte2)
RT2 = data.frame(RT2$p.value)
RT3 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte3, Laag$Ruimte3)
RT3 = data.frame(RT3$p.value)
RT4 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte4, Laag$Ruimte4)
RT4 = data.frame(RT4$p.value)
RT5 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte5, Laag$Ruimte5)
RT5 = data.frame(RT5$p.value)
RT6 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte6, Laag$Ruimte6)
RT6 = data.frame(RT6$p.value)
RT7 <- t.test(Hoog$Ruimte7, Laag$Ruimte7)
RT7 = data.frame(RT7$p.value)
RT0 <- t.test(Hoog$`Gemiddeld /n Openbare Ruimte`, Laag$`Gemiddeld /n Openbare Ruimte`)
RT0 = data.frame(RT0$p.value)
#needed for getting the P.value of a t-test


dat2 <- data.frame(Laagopgeleid, Hoogopgeleid) %>% round(digits = 2)
gem.beoordeling <- c(apply(dat2, 2, sort), RT0$RT0.p.value)

dat4 <- data.frame(Ruimte1 = c(LR1, HR1, RT1$RT1.p.value),
                   Ruimte2 = c(LR2, HR2, RT2$RT2.p.value),
                   Ruimte3 = c(LR3, HR3, RT3$RT3.p.value),
                   Ruimte4 = c(LR4, HR4, RT4$RT4.p.value),
                   Ruimte5 = c(LR5, HR5, RT5$RT5.p.value),
                   Ruimte6 = c(LR6, HR6, RT6$RT6.p.value),
                   Ruimte7 = c(LR7, HR7, RT7$RT7.p.value),
                   gem.beoordeling)
colnames(dat4) <- c("Ruimte1", "Ruimte2", "Ruimte3", "Ruimte4", "Ruimte5", "Ruimte6", "Ruimte7", "Gem.beoordeling")
rownames(dat4) <- c("Laagopgeleid", "Hoogopgeleid", "T-test")
dat4

datt2 <- xtable(dat4, digits = 3)

date2 <- flextable(dat4) %>%
  fontsize(part = "header", size = 20) %>%
  fontsize(part = "body", size = 18) %>%
  align_text_col(align = "left") %>% 
  align_nottext_col(align = "center") %>% 
  width(width = 1.8) %>%
  width(j = 1, width = 3.3) %>%
  height_all(height = .5) %>%
  border_inner(border = std_border) %>% 
  font(fontname = "Open Sans") %>%
  colformat_double(i = c("Laagopgeleid", "Hoogopgeleid"), digits = 2) %>% 
  color(part = "header", color = d)
date2


dat3 <- data.frame(Laagopgeleid, Hoogopgeleid) %>% round(digits = 0)
Range <- apply(dat3, 2, sort)
Range <- as.character(sapply(Range, digits_to_words))
```

Comment: Hi, why are you using xtable before creating the flextable? If I remember correctly, xtable is casting all data to characters. Could you try with `dat4 %>% flextable %>% fontsize()...`?

Comment: This seems to fix my issue with the decimals [i = c("Hoogopgeleid", "Laagopgeleid"), digits = 2)] But it removes the rownames. Any solution for that?

Comment: you can use function `row.names` to get them and then cbind or `tibble::rownames_to_column()`

Comment: For some reason tibble::rownames_to_column() brings me right back to where I started as I cant change the decimal anymore. It keeps saying that the rowname is unknown. And with row.names I assume you mean row.names(date2)? I tried this but it returns with Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 'dimnames' applied to non-array

Comment: could you provide the data for dat4? it would be easier for us to reproduce your issue and to propose a solution.